# Open only one slider at a time

Tags: jquery, css

I've been struggling with this for the past few weeks but am completely stuck! I'm hoping someone can offer advice so I can finally start working on the rest of my project.

I'm trying to build my portfolio and have divided it into four sections. When I click on the 'portfolio buttons' it is currently opening ALL .slidingDivs simultaneously, with the last one displayed on top. How can I improve the jQuery so it only targets the menu item the user is clicking on? (i.e. when I click on 'web', I want it to open only the 'web' .slidingDiv)

I'm sure it's very obvious, but thank you for any advice you can offer!

http://jsfiddle.net/pootletootle/u02au0vv/9/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

    $(window).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
        $(this).stop(true, false).bxSlider();
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Uhm, would you please create a jsfiddle before you get downvotes for just dropping all the code in here ? :)

Comment: Ooh sorry - I'm new so wasn't sure of the etiquette! I'm at work at the moment but when I get home I'll make sure I rectify this - thank you for the advice!

Comment: You are welcome, when you post, your question must be clear, show some research and stuff you tried, try not to use words like "it's not working", be more specific on what your problem is and how it should work and you should try to always use a jsfiddle or jsbin for your code so that we can see it in action and debug faster.

Comment: Thank you - have just created a jsfiddle (hope I've done it correctly :/ apologies if I've got it wrong!) The slider isn't working in the jsfiddle, but as this isn't my issue (and it's working okay on my website) I assume this is okay - just need advice on the 'targeting one thing at a time' issue. Thanks!

Comment: Good, +1 from me for your first question and for the attention to the suggestions. Now, did you try @playmaker 's answer?

Comment: Just gave it a try and commented below. I think I must be tweaking the wrong parts as I couldn't get it to work just yet, but thank you so much for your help so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the updated code (http://jsfiddle.net/u02au0vv/13/)

Based on the fact that you have a class for each button. Changes you need to make are as follows:

- Add the respective class to slidingDiv class
- Add the respective class to close button class
- Update the jQuery .click() function

**Note:** Make sure that the unique class is the 2nd class in all the buttons, close and slidingDiv (else change the class selector index in the function)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".slidingDiv").hide();
  $(".show_hide").show();

  $('.show_hide').click(function(event) {
    var i = $(event.target).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    $('.slidingDiv.' + i).slideToggle();

    $(window).ready(function() {
      $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
      $(this).stop(true, false).bxSlider();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
@charset"utf-8";

/* CSS Document 

#louise-scroller img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
}*/

html,
body,
.container,
.louise-scroller,
.louise-scroller section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
/*__________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Navigation

*/

#louise-scroller nav {
  width: 100%;
  top: 5%;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}
#louise-scroller nav a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0px 0.2em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
#louise-scroller nav a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
}
#louise-scroller nav a:hover:after {
  color: #888888;
}
#louise-scroller nav a.louise-current:after {
  background: #888888;
}
.louise-current {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
/* background-attachment does the trick */

#louise-scroller section {
  position: relative;
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes mymove {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes ohmove {
  from {
    right: -100%;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes ohmove {
  from {
    right: -100%;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
  }
}
#louise-scroller p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
/*__________________________________________________________________________________________________________

Portfolio

*/

#louise-scroller #portfolio {
  background: #999999;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  /* custom background-position */
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  /* ie8- graceful degradation */
  background-position: 50% 50%9 !important;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 80px 0;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*padding-bottom: 500px;*/
  padding: 0;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a {
  background: #222222;
  background-size: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 114px !important;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 167px 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 500px !important;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a.branding,
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a.graphics {
  background: #444444;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a.graphics,
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a.illustration {
  float: left;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-container a.illustration {
  background: url('images/Large/Large_140925_Portfolio_Illustration2.jpg') no-repeat;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-row {
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto !important;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-left,
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
#louise-scroller #portfolio .ss-left {
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
}
/* Pop Up */

#louise-scroller #portfolio .reveal {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.slidingDiv {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.slidingDiv #close {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;
  color: #444444;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 29px;
  padding: 1px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  top: 2%;
  width: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
}
.show_hide {
  display: none;
}
.bx-wrapper {
  position: absolute !important;
}
.bx-wrapper img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.bxslider img {
  background: #FFCCFF;
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #CC99FF;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #99CCFF;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #CCFFFF;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #FFFF66;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #FF9933;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #FF6666;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #9966FF;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #6699FF;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #00FF00;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #996633;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #CC0000;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #993366;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #000052;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #0099CC;
}
.bxslider img#two {
  background: #669999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="portfolio">
  <h2>Portfolio</h2>

  <!-- Portfolio Buttons-->
  <div id="ss-container" class="ss-container">
    <div class="ss-row">
      <div class="ss-left">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide web" id="0">Web</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-right">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide graphics" id="1">Graphics</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ss-row ss-medium">
      <div class="ss-left">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide branding">Branding</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ss-right">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide illustration">Illustration</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Pop Up & Flexslider -->
  <div class="slidingDiv web">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide web" id="close">X</a>
    <ul class="bxslider web active">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.bayesian-inference.com/images/ban-samplesize.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_2.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_3.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_4.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slidingDiv graphics">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide graphics" id="close">X</a>
    <ul class="bxslider graphics">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.stardust.com/mm5/graphics/00000001/Established-Sons-Two-Timer-Clock-xl3.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_6.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_7.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_8.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slidingDiv branding">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide branding" id="close">X</a>
    <ul class="bxslider branding">
      <li>
        <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_10.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_11.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_12.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="slidingDiv illustration">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="show_hide illustration" id="close">X</a>
    <ul class="bxslider illustration">
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_13.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_14.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_15.jpg" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <img src="images/Louise_Flanagan_16.jpg" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

*Note:* I've changed the first img src in the top 3 divs to verify whether the code 2was working or not.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I tried adding and id of "close1", "close2" etc to the a tags, and replaced the jquery with what you suggested but I'm afraid I couldn't get it to work (definitely a lack of jquery skills on my part!). I literally copied and pasted your jquery over the

Comment: section of my jquery:

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function () {
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();

Hope this is what you meant?

Comment: Also, each button has a unique class that corresponds to the div's class I want it to open (e.g. 'web', 'illustration' etc) so do I need to give them unique corresponding ids instead. Thanks again - really appreciate everyone's help :)

Comment: Hey, I've updated the code. Have a look. Also, please provide such information in the original code henceforth. Can change the approach used :)

Comment: Thank you so much - that works a treat, you've been a brilliant help! :)

Comment: My pleasure. Please tick the answer to close the question as answered.